# How do I write into google sheets, the city_name column from my groupby result in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

So I had data for some hotels along with their city_name like this:

```
city_name     hotel_id
A             X
B             Y
.             .
.             .
.             .
Z             XX
```

now i grouped all the hotels from the same city and found out their counts using this line:
`onlybcount = dfbb.groupby('city_name').count()` where dfbb is the df containing all the data.

The result looked something like this:

```
           hotel_id(count)
city_name

A            20
B             5
C            15
```

Now when i wrote these resultant groups to a google sheet, only the hotelid count was printed, the city_name was not. I also need to get all the city_name in my google sheet. How do I do that? The data frame isn't storing city_name as a column that's why it's not getting written into the sheet, I guess.

Comment: do `df = df.reset_index()` just before writing to google sheet.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Can you share your code of writing to google sheets. groupby- > reset index -> write. this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `city_name` in the `groupby` is not a column but index.

It would be helpful to understand how you are inserting the values in google sheets.
Since we don't have that piece of code, I'll assume is not including indexes.

You can make the `groupby` to return city_name as a *normal* column instead of an index by using the `as_index` flag.

```
onlybcount = dfbb.groupby('city_name', as_index=False).count()
```

Comment: since you mentioned it worked. I would like to say what you did here and `reset_index` are same thing. I guess you were not doing `df=df.reset_index()` and were just doing `df.reset_inedx()`

Comment: Hmm, right. I noticed it just now that i only typed df.reset_index() so it did not update the df.